# Unable to run script despite escalating privilege in Ansible

Tags: oracle, shell, ansible, sqlplus, ansible-2.x

Im trying to run a shell script on the host machine after copying it over there using ansible. The script has 777 permissions.

Please read the below question as it gives the full scope of the actual issue that we are trying to deal with

[Set different ORACLE_HOME and PATH environment variable using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224408/set-different-oracle-home-and-path-environment-variable-using-ansible)

```
- name: Run the Script [List]
  shell: "/tmp/sqlscript/sql_select.sh {{item}} >> /tmp/sqlscript/output.out"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: oracle
  register: orh
  with_items: "{{ factor_dbs.split('\n') }}"
```

Below is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/bin/gsd_xenv $1 &> /dev/null

sqlplus -s <<EOF
/ as sysdba
set heading off


select d.name||','||i.instance_name||','||i.host_name||';' from v\$database d,v\$instance i;

EOF
```

Despite escalating the privileges, I observed that the task is not executing unless I add environment variables like below

```
- name: Run the script [List]
  shell: "/tmp/sqlscript/oracle_home.sh {{item}} >> /tmp/sqlscript/orahome.out"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: oracle
  environment:
     PATH: "/home/oracle/bin:/usr/orasys/12.1.0.2r10/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/ucb:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc:/usr/local/bin:/oradata/epdmat/goldengate/config/sys"
     ORACLE_HOME: "/usr/orasys/12.1.0.2r10"
  register: orh
  with_items: "{{ factor_dbs.split('\n') }}"
```

However this playbook needs to be run across different hosts which have different path and oracle_home variables.

My question is, why doest the task run despite escalating the permissions. When I try to run the same script manually by logging into the server and after doing "sudo su oracle", it seems to be running fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you actually set your environment variables. There is a difference in executing a script when you are logged in at a remote machine, and running a script over `ssh` as Ansible does (see e.g., [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879364/differentiate-interactive-login-and-non-interactive-non-login-shell)). Depending on the type of shell and your system, different bash profiles are loaded.